# owl carousel how to use scroll bar Horizontal?

Tags: jquery, owl-carousel

I am using owl-carousel js library. I need Horizontal scroll bar feature. I tried this:

```
 $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({
            Horizontal: true, // not working this
            items : 4,
            itemsDesktop : [1199,3],
            itemsDesktopSmall : [979,3],
            itemsTablet: [2400,4], //2 items between 600 and 0
            itemsMobile :[1200,4]           
        });
```

[Click this reference](http://codepen.io/OwlFonk/pen/qhgjb/)

Comment: where have you seen a scrollbar feature? i dont see this option in the docs or in any demo

Comment: According to https://github.com/OwlCarousel2/OwlCarousel2/issues/1240, this is a feature request that has not been implemented into the plugin. However, there is another plugin that does what I think you need (https://github.com/maksbd19/owlcarousel-scrollbar-plugin).

I'm assuming that the scroll bar will be used as a control and not for overflow purposes... because there would be no point in using a carousel that overflows horizontally.